# Warning: require_once(../initialize.php): failed to open stream and Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required problem

Tags: php

I am running my system to 000webhost and this issue pops out when I open it

> Warning: require_once(../initialize.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd4/040/17993040/public_html/EPS/classes/DBConnection.php on line 3

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../initialize.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /storage/ssd4/040/17993040/public_html/EPS/classes/DBConnection.php on line 3

and this are the code files

**DBConnection.php**

```
<?php
if(!defined('id17993040_epsdb')){
    require_once("../initialize.php");
}
class DBConnection{

    private $host = "local_host";
    private $username = "id17993040_root";
    private $password = "********";
    private $database = "id17993040_epsdb";
    
    public $conn;
    
    public function __construct(){

        if (!isset($this->conn)) {
            
            $this->conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);
            
            if (!$this->conn) {
                echo 'Cannot connect to database server';
                exit;
            }            
        }    
        
    }
    public function __destruct(){
        $this->conn->close();
    }
}
?>
```

**initialize.php**

```
    <?php
$dev_data = array('id'=>'-1','firstname'=>'Developer','lastname'=>'','username'=>'dev_oretnom','password'=>'**********','last_login'=>'','date_updated'=>'','date_added'=>'');
if(!defined('base_url')) define('base_url','https://web-silverconcha.000webhostapp.com/EPS/');
if(!defined('base_app')) define('base_app', str_replace('\\','/',__DIR__).'/' );
if(!defined('dev_data')) define('dev_data',$dev_data);
if(!defined('DB_SERVER')) define('DB_SERVER',"localhost");
if(!defined('DB_USERNAME')) define('DB_USERNAME',"id17993040_root");
if(!defined('DB_PASSWORD')) define('DB_PASSWORD',"************");
if(!defined('DB_NAME')) define('DB_NAME',"id17993040_epsdb");
?>
```

What are the solutions to this? Sorry for asking just a newbie

UPDATE:
This was the filesystem
[filedir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUsjx.png)

[filedir2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J57D.png)

[filedir3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzoyh.png)

Comment: Make sure the files it's complaining about are in the correct folder on the server

Comment: I have already done directing it to the right directory but still the error shows

Comment: Can you show your folder structure? Which folder is `initialize.php` in in relation to `/storage/ssd4/040/17993040/public_html`?

Comment: I am using free 000webhost and the file manager only shows the public_html folder along with tmp

Comment: `have already done directing it to the right directory`...well PHP disagrees with you, and computers don't know how to tell lies. So I suggest you double check your assumptions. It's difficult for us to help more because we can't see your filesystem.

Comment: The filesystem is on the updated post

Answer (score 0):

PHP throws a fatal error when you are using **require_once()** and it doesn't find the file, which causes script to stop, unlike **include_once()** which will only show you a warning that it could not find the file.

So it's simply telling you " I can't find the file that you asked for in line 3"

You can try

```
$realPath = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);

require_once("$realPath/initialize.php");
```

Highly recommend to read and learn more about these:

[realpath](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.realpath.php)